# Global PHP Handling

Tags: php, nginx

I have a NGINX server which has "virtual" directories I am handling with a LOCATION and setting the ROOT manually. My issue is that I am ending up with a bunch of duplicate PHP handling blocks. Like this:

```
        location ~ ^(/resources/|/javascript/|/order/|/sales_template/) {
            root /srv/mysite/web/web-main;

            location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

                    #set $full_filename

                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

                    fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
                    fastcgi_param APP_RUNTIME cloud;
                    fastcgi_param APP_MODE sub_site;
                    fastcgi_param X-TEST $uri;
                    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /srv/mysite/web/web-main;
            }
      }


    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

            #set $full_filename

            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
            fastcgi_param APP_RUNTIME cloud;
            fastcgi_param APP_MODE sub_site;
            fastcgi_param X-TEST $uri;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /srv/mysite/web/web-main;
    }
```

My question is: Is there a better way to handle serving PHP pages globally? I understand the above example is fairly simple, but I expect this config to get more complex over time.

Comment: This would get much more attention at ServerFault